# Rename multiple files for one BibTeX entry in JabRef

Tags: bibtex, jabref

The funcionallity of renaming files is great, but I have some bibtex entries, which have mutiple pdf files attached. 
So only one file of the same type is renamed using `\bibtexkey` as *Filename format pattern*:

```
@InProceedings{MustermannTitelOfThisPaper,
  author    = {Mustermann, Thomas and Musterfrau, Olivia},
  title     = {Titel of this paper},
  file      = {:img/MustermannTitelOfThisPaper.png:PNG image;Poster:pdf/MustermannTitelOfThisPaper.pdf:PDF;:pdf/DifferentName.pdf:PDF},
}
```

with the files:
- MustermannTitelOfThisPaper.pdf
- DifferentName.pdf

**But** what I need and haven't found yet is also a possibility of adding a number, if needed, like:

```
@InProceedings{MustermannTitelOfThisPaper,
  author    = {Mustermann, Thomas and Musterfrau, Olivia},
  title     = {Titel of this paper},
  file      = {:img/MustermannTitelOfThisPaper.png:PNG image;Poster:pdf/MustermannTitelOfThisPaper1.pdf:PDF;:pdf/MustermannTitelOfThisPaper2.pdf:PDF},
}
```

with the files
- MustermannTitelOfThisPaper1.pdf
- MustermannTitelOfThisPaper2.pdf

Comment: Hi, JabRef dev here, I think that is currently not possible, but I will look into it, if I find a way